# Hide Visual Studio toolbars (without fullscreen)

Tags: visual-studio, toolbar

the previous answers to this question are about going fullscreen or the navigation bar, but I want all toolbars removed without fullscreen. Isn't there a simple way to do this? (Visual Studio Express 2015)

Comment: It would be better if you would post your own solution as an answer and not as an edit.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so I found the (embarrassingly simple) answer:

View -> Toolbars

Deselect all toolbars.

To also hide the navigation bar go to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> All languages